# CD-Rom drive only shows a " desktop.ini." file after burning image file

Tags: windows-7

After burning an image file to CD , no files show in the CD content of the CD-Rom drive,   except a  Notepad file called " desktop" .Nothing else! Where is the rest of the  files supposedly burned? This happens with a Rosetta Stone  language program, no matter which burning software I use ( Imgburn, Daemon tools, etc.).

Also, when I mount a drive, it cannot contain more than one IMG file at a time, so I have to use multiple Virtual drives, which is visually confusing.  How can I mount a batch of Img files in the same virtual drive?

Comment: First I have NEVER heard of mounting multiple image drives to a single virtual drive.  Second it sounds like the images you are trying to burn are not actually disk images.

Comment: It definitely seems like you lack some understanding on how ISO's work and what you can/can't do with them. http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ht/burnisofile.htm & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image

Comment: THe ISO image is off the Rosetta Stone program. It is not corrupted because it works with a virtual drive.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first off, think of Virtual Drives as a single DVD drive. They can only hold one DVD at a time just as a Physical Drive can

Second, whatever you are using to burn the image is failing unless the .IMG (or .ISO) file itself is bad. There's really not a whole lot to it other than that. It sounds like windows disc burning utility is being used here so I would recommend 'Ashampoo Burning Studio 6 Free' (google it) as it never fails on me instead of the default windows burner.

Comment: It could also be a bad CD in the RW category.

Comment: A point well made, I hadn't thought about that, I just assumed the OP was using different DVD-R's. (I say DVD-R because I believe Rosetta Stone is much too large to fit on a single CD)